# How to call python module in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I do have the following folder structure for python scripts.

[image]

From Python I can run a script in folder Feed2Scripts as follows. Can this be possible in Robot Frame Work through imported libraries? > Note that I have common scripts in ‘GeneralScripts’ used by all other scripts in different folders

```
  ../Scripts>python –m Feed2Scripts.Script1 param1
```

If I just `import Feed2Scripts/Script1.py` as a library in RF, then It is failing to load libraries defined 'GeneralScripts'

Comment: Anything you put in PYTHONPATH can be imported into robot.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, will try that

Comment: What does "failing to load libraries" mean? Do you get an error when you run your tests? If so, what's the error?

Comment: its working now after adding the location to PYTHONPATH . Thanks  Bryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you set your python path on RIDE's `Tools->Preferences->Importing` `Pythonpath` so it does include your library **and all its dependencies** (imported modules and so on), like this:

[image: RIDE Preferences - Pythonpath]

*(If your library is distributed via PIP, just `pip install my_library_package_name` instead, on the same environment you are running Robotframework/RIDE)*

Then you can add the library to your test suite on the `add library` dialog you can open by pressing the `library` button on the `Edit` tab you can see when you select the suite:

[image: RIDE - Add library to test suite]

After that, all keywords defined in your library will be available for use in any test of the test suite. You will see a `Library` import sentence on the `Settings` section of the header of your suite's code (On your text editor or RIDE's `Text Edit` tab of the suite:

[image: RIDE test suite Library Import Text Edit Tab]

Sometimes RIDE doesn't recognize the keywords on a recently added or modified library right away. In that case, `Save all` (`CTRL+SHIFT+S`) and restart RIDE to fix the issue.

Also, watch out for the library entry showing up in red on the suite import list on RIDE's `Edit` tab; it means something went wrong when trying to import the library. If you need to know what, you can find the trace on RIDE's `Tools->View Ride Log`.

Comment: Be careful of your terminology: robot framework and RIDE are two different things. When you say "Robot Framework's Tools->Preferences->Importing", that's not a robot framework setting, that's a RIDE setting. These instructions only work if you're using RIDE, but won't work if you're using some other editor.

Comment: Thanks NotGaeL, As Bryan Mentioned , I'm able to import Library after adding the location to PYTHONPATH

Comment: @Bryan Oakley you're right, I edited it to `RIDE`, which is what I was referring to. Thanks for pointing it out! :-)